# How to modify the 'nodes' behaviour in Zingchart

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, zingchart

I plot some series of data with Zingchart. The data is one entry per second, per set. The result is the following graph:

[image: zoom out graph].

I am happy with this result. I get an overview of the plot that is very fast using `"exact":false` as plot attribute. Afterwards, I want to be able to 'zoom in' to see the detail:

[image: zoom in graph]

And now I have too much detail. The attributes I have for `plot` are:

```
          "maxNodes":2000,
          "maxTrackers":2000,
```

I have been trying to *play* with those numbers but at the end, if I reduce the number I just have to zoom-in more. As I understand I get one node/tracker/information popup per data entry in the current status of the visualization only if there are less nodes than the limit defined.

**Would it be possible to indicate Zingchart to place the nodes not in every data point, but with some kind of interval or intention?.**

For example, in the second graph I would like to have nodes at the beginning / end and on the *jump* that the line makes. Or local maximums / minimums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options.

1) You **could** change the `"max-nodes"` to a lower number. `"max-nodes"` just determines how many nodes are drawn while `"max-trackers"` determines how many you can interact with.

2) You could also add the following to your plot object...

```
marker: {
  rules: [
    {
      rule: '%i%5 > 0',
      visible: false
    }
  ]
}
```

What that does it it checks the index (`%i`) of each marker. If the index of the marker modulo 5 is greater than 0, we don't display the marker (node). That means that all nodes except those evenly divisible by 5 will be hidden.

I'm on the ZingChart team. Let me know if this helps. Holla if you've got more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that the tooltip was popping out only on nodes and now I see that's not actually the case and the node is just a decoration for the plot.

Comment: @eballes happy to help! Yeah, the are purely aesthetic. If you want an even faster rendering chart, you could remove the nodes (markers) all together with "marker": { "visible": false }